# statement not getting implemented in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to remove the punctuation and the numeric values from the string. I have tried the following statement:

```
name_check = ''.join([letter for letter in name_check if letter not in string.punctuation or not letter.isdigit()])
```

when I give input as `tom.alter99999`, it returns the exactly same value, whereas I expect to give the value as `tomalter`.

Just me what I need to change in the statement so that I get the desired output.

Comment: just modify the `or` to `and`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used an `or` conditional, which means that it'll always be true that any given letter is either not `punctuation` or not a digit.

Changing your conditional to an `and` will work.

```
name_check = ''.join([letter for letter in name_check
                      if letter not in string.punctuation
                      and not letter.isdigit()])
```

You can also use `str.maketrans` and transliterate your string, replacing all punctuation and digits in a string with nothing.

```
import string

translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation + string.digits)

print('tom.alter99999'.translate(translator))
```

Comment: It helped... still I have resolve the condition with or method too, I will post it. I accept your answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson - your solution also works. I added an alternative that uses transliteration via `str.maketrans` to remove punctuation and digits from any string.

Answer (score 1):

you need `and` instead `or`

```
name_check = ''.join([letter for letter in name_check if letter not in string.punctuation or not letter.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `re` library

```
import re
name='tom.alter99999'
res = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]',name)
print("".join(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement I solved with or condition too. Here is what I did:

```
name_check = ''.join([letter for letter in name_check if not (letter in string.punctuation or letter.isdigit())])
```

I got the output as:  `tomalter`